# Language Token not translated on sidebar when using the Collection extension for MediaWiki

Tags: collections, mediawiki

I am using the Collection extension for MediaWiki to allow for generation of PDF books based on content located in my wiki. When I am logged out of my wiki, the extension works fine and the sidebar on the Main Page contains:

```
Print/export
  Create a book
  Download as PDF
  Printable version
```

However when I log in the sidebar contains:

```
coll-print_export
  &lt;coll-create_a_book&gt;
  &lt;coll-download_as&gt;
  Printable version
```

I've verified that the tokens' translations for coll-print_export, coll-create_a_booklet and coll-download_as exist, along with their associated tooltip entries, in the 'en' messages array, and that my system and profile language are set to en.

Nevertheless, the display when I am logged in is the language token, not the translation. I've tested logins with multiple users as well. The issue seems isolated to the Collection extension, as every other part of the sidebar works as expected. Also, note that while Printable Version appears under the print/export menu, it appears to not be defined as part of Collection, and it appears to be working fine.

Any assistance or advice for where I can look to identify the resolution for this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Update: I've also noticed that if I follow the link to create_a_book, none of the tokens on that page are translated, either. The page displays as: &lt;coll-book_creator&gt;

<coll-book_creator_intro>
&lt;coll-start_book_creator&gt;
&lt;coll-cancel&gt;

<coll-book_creator_help>

Comment: Do you have any caching enabled for your wiki? Something like xcache?

Comment: PLease specify exact version (and ideally git revision) of core and Collection code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Because it only happens when you login, I suspect it depends on your preferences, probably your interface language. As Christian said, it's likely to be cache for the system messages.

Try `php maintenance/rebuildLocalisationCache.php --force`. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RebuildLocalisationCache.php